# What effect does this code in PHP?

Tags: php

```
session_name('MoodleSession'.$CFG->sessioncookie);  //设置当前session名称为MoodleSession
   /*
    * 
    */
    if (check_php_version('5.2.0')) {
        session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly);
    } else {
        session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure);
    }

    @session_start();
```

Comment: It does half a dozen different things, most of which you could learn about by copy/pasting the function names that are called into the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pasted it in one liner

```
<?php
session_name('MoodleSession'.$CFG->sessioncookie); //设置当前session名称为MoodleSession /* * */ if (check_php_version('5.2.0')) { session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly); } else { session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure); }
```

the only executed function would be `session_name('MoodleSession'.$CFG->sessioncookie);` because you are commenting the rest of the line with a `//`

What does this piece of code?

```
<?php
@session_start();
```

If you prepend a piece of code in PHP with an @, the PHP interpreter will not throw any warnings, **which is a bad practice and error prone**.

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) as defined by http://php.net/:

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.
>
> When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will
>   call the open and read session save handlers. These will either be a
>   built-in save handler provided by default or by PHP extensions (such
>   as SQLite or Memcached); or can be custom handler as defined by
>   session_set_save_handler(). The read callback will retrieve any
>   existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will
>   be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION
>   superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back
>   to PHP session handling.

If you need more info I can update my answer. Maybe you should paste your code better, I think you have it bad formatted.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, saw your new code :P

As my previous statement about `@session_start()` stands, your code just updates a session name to `"MoodleSession"` plus the value of `$CFG->sessioncookie`.

The middle part

```
if (check_php_version('5.2.0')) {
    session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly);
} else {
    session_set_cookie_params(0, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $CFG->cookiesecure);
}
```

checks the PHP version. According to the [changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#refsect1-function.session-set-cookie-params-changelog) of [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), a `httponly` parameter was added, so in case of running the PHP 5.2 version, it will execute session_set_cookie_params with the extra parameter.